# How do I export function from C++ DLL and use in delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I am trying to create a DLL in C++ and export a function.

This is my C++ code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void DLLMain(){

}

__declspec(dllexport) void xMain(){
MessageBox(NULL,L"Test",L"Test",NULL);
}
```

This is my delphi code:

```
program prjTestDllMain;

Uses
  Windows;

Var
  xMainPrc:procedure;stdcall;
  handle : THandle;
begin
    handle := LoadLibrary('xdll.dll');
    if handle <> 0 then
    begin
        MessageBox(0,'DLL Loaded', 0, 0);
        @xMainPrc := GetProcAddress(handle, 'xMain');
        if @xMainPrc <> nil then
            MessageBox(0,'Function Loaded', 0, 0)
        else
          MessageBox(0,'Function Not Loaded', 0, 0);
        MessageBox(0,'Process End', 0, 0);
        FreeLibrary(handle);
    end else
      MessageBox(0,'DLL Not Loaded', 0, 0);
end.
```

I get a messagebox for "DLL Loaded" just fine. But I get "Function Not Loaded" afterwards. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can export it as a C function (`__cdecl`), so that it has a nice name on the exports table.

> **Name-decoration convention**:
>   Underscore character (_) is prefixed to names, except when exporting __cdecl functions that use C linkage.

So basically, your function will have the name `xMain` in the exports table.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void xMain()
```

And in the Delphi part, you just specify `cdecl` and call it normally:

```
var
  xMainPrc: procedure; cdecl;
```

For example:

```
if @xMainPrc <> nil then
begin
  MessageBox(0,'Function Loaded', 0, 0);
  xMainPrc;
end;
```

Comment: The function is already exported as `__cdecl` as that is C/C++'s default calling convention. By using `__cdecl`, you force the exported name to have a leading underscore, and thus you have to import the function with that underscore. If you do not want the unerscore, you have to either use a .def file to remove it, or use `_stdcall` instead of `__cdecl`.

Comment: If you use `__cdecl` without a .def file, then you have to use `GetProcAddress()` like this: `@xMainPrc := GetProcAddress(handle, '_xMain');`

Comment: That's why I didn't use `__cdecl` in my example, because he was using `stdcall` in Delphi and I hinted him that it'd be `cdecl` (he didn't write `__stdcall` for the C++ part). The parenthesis (`__cdecl`) I wrote is just to advice him that it's the default calling convention. Thus, alternatively, he could have used `stdcall`, as long as he write `__stdcall` and `extern "C"`. That's also why I quoted MSDN, so he doesn't use `__cdecl` without `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 2):

Export the function using the `__stcall` calling convention (especially since you are trying to import it using the `stdcall` calling convention in Delphi), and use `extern "C"` to remove any exported name decorating:

**MyDll.h**:

```
#ifndef MyDLLH
#define MyDLLH

#ifdef __BUILDING_DLL
#define MYDLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

MYDLLEXPORT void __stdcall xMain();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

.

**MyDll.cpp**:

```
#define __BUILDING_DLL
#include "MyDll.h"

#include <Windows.h>

void DLLMain()
{
}

void __stdcall xMain()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Test", L"Test", NULL);
}
```

.

**prjTestDllMain.dpr**:

```
program prjTestDllMain;

uses
  Windows;

var
  xMainPrc: procedure; stdcall;
  handle : THandle;
begin
  handle := LoadLibrary('xdll.dll');
  if handle <> 0 then
  begin
    MessageBox(0,'DLL Loaded', 0, 0);
    @xMainPrc := GetProcAddress(handle, 'xMain');
    if @xMainPrc <> nil then
    begin
      MessageBox(0,'Function Loaded', 0, 0)
      xMainPrc();
    end else
      MessageBox(0,'Function Not Loaded', 0, 0);
    MessageBox(0,'Process End', 0, 0);
    FreeLibrary(handle);
  end else
    MessageBox(0,'DLL Not Loaded', 0, 0);
end.
```

Alternatively:

**prjTestDllMain.dpr**:

```
program prjTestDllMain;

uses
  Windows;

procedure xMain; stdcall; extern 'MyDll.dll';

begin
  MessageBox(0,'DLL Loaded', 0, 0);
  xMain();
  MessageBox(0,'Process End', 0, 0);
end.
```